# 'undeclared identifier' error even though variable was declared earlier in the code

Tags: c, cs50

`int` variable `h` is declared on line 10, when the user inputs the value.

However when the code compiles it says it's undeclared.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("How tall would you like your pyramid?\n");
    bool inc = true;
    while (inc)
    {
        int h = GetInt();
        if (h <= 23 && h >= 1)
        {
            inc = false;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("your value needs to be between 1 and 26\n");
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<=h; i++)
    {
        printf("#\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: c don't support OTG variable decalaration.

Comment: H is declared in the while scope, so it's undeclared outside of it.

Comment: You are using `h` outside the scope where it was declared. Voting to close this as simple typo.

Comment: _scope of a variable_

Comment: Why all those downvotes?

Comment: @Lundin This is not a typo, it's a beginner who doesn't understand variable scope.

Comment: @alk, Yeah, right ?

Comment: @interjay if `h == 5` then h <= 23 and h >= 1, so yes, it will be true.

Comment: @GillBates You're right, I misread that.

Comment: @interjay Okay then it should be closed as duplicate to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090836/c-variables-scope.

Answer (score 7):

Your variable `h` is in another castle:

```
while (inc)
{
    int h = GetInt();
    if (h <= 23 && h >= 1)
    {
        inc = false;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("your value needs to be between 1 and 26\n");
    }
    // h is destroyed after this line and is no longer visible.
}

for (int i=0; i<=h; i++)
{
    printf("#\n");
}
```

Brackets indicate scope, scope indicates variable visibility.
`h` is declared inside the scope of the `while` loop, `h` is not visible outside that scope, it is not visible outside the `}` of the loop. If you want to access it outside of the loop you should put it outside of the loop:

```
int h = -1;
while (inc)
{
    h = GetInt();
    if (h <= 23 && h >= 1)
    {
        inc = false;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("your value needs to be between 1 and 26\n");
    }
}

for (int i=0; i<=h; i++)
{
    printf("#\n");
}
// h is still visible here.
```

Comment: `h = GetInt();` should be inside the loop.

Comment: *If* `inc` would be false then the for-loop's break condition would read out an uninitialised `h`. Better do `int h = -1;`.

Comment: @alk The program wouldn't make much sense then, would it?  Nevertheless, for the sake of good practices I'll edit it.

Comment: ... and for the sake of writing ***robust*** code. :-)

Comment: Oh ok so in C a varible is only localized to the castle it was declared in ?

Comment: @DavidHancock Correct.